# 2002 Honda Odyssey - how much extra labor to replace backing plates as part of brake job

Tags: honda, brakes, odyssey

I've been experiencing vibration when braking in my 2002 Odyssey and took it into a shop. Shop is recommending a brake job all around, which makes sense.

In addition, the mechanic noticed that the rear "dust sheilds" or "backing plates" are heavily corroded, and indicated that while they could try to re-use them, they recommend replacing them while the brake work is being done since there is a lot of overlap in the labour.

However, the price they are quoting to replace the backing plates doubles the cost of the brake job. It seems high to me, since the brakes will be apart regardless, and the parts aren't particularly expensive.

So I'm wondering, what additional labor, beyond the work required for the brake job, is involved in changing the backing plates?

Comment: A quick google search says they aren't cheap. For example the backing plate costs twice as much as a pair of rear brake shoes. If they have to take the backing plates off to do the rest of the work, the labour costs should be the same either way.

Comment: There is a major difference between "dust shield" and "backing plate." A dust shield is cheap and super easy to replace. It is made of thin sheet metal, and just keeps rocks from flying into your front disc brakes. The backing plates are plates at the back of drum brakes. They are quite a bit thicker and more durable, because they both keep rocks from flying into the rear drum brakes, and hold the force of all friction applied by the brakes. Replacing backing plates would significantly increase the cost and difficulty of replacing the rear brakes.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The 02 has disc brakes all around, he initially referred to them as dust shields but then called them backing plates later in the discussion.  Apparently part of the issue is some parking brake components being mounted to or routed via the dust shield.  I had a followup call with them and asked if there was room to move on the total and he said the prices he gave me were the worst case. I wonder if he was just quoting the standard cost of doing the two jobs separately.  I'm interested to hear if anyone is familiar with the specific details on the odyssey.

Comment: Go get a quote from another place and decide.

Comment: Iirc you have to remove the hub to do the backing plates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It involves removing the caliper, caliper bracket, rotor, hub nut, hub, all of the parking brake components, and reassembling.

It's a lot of work.  The picture below gives you an idea of what's involved.

Book rate labor for just the hub removal is 1.6 hours, both sides, just by itself.  Add around another 2.0 to R&R the parking brake components etc.

I would get new hubs/bearings while you are already in there.  Those parts, unless it's at a dealer, are fairly inexpensive.  It will cost *even more*, but it will be cheap insurance and allow you to take advantage of the labor "overlap" as you put it.

[image]